Plane rotation is not working in Reality View visionOS
How can we rotate a plane in reality view in visionOS after tracking image in AR, to achieve this I had to add some sphere/box after detecting image and then I have added a plane as a child of that sphere/box and I'm able to rotate a plane now, instead is there any way to directly rotate a plane in parent view without adding any other 3d sphere/box.
Also is there any way to change a pivot point of generated plane, currently it is centre of a plane but I want a top left corner as a pivot point of plane?
I tried to generate a plane once I detected a image in AR and tried to rotate a plane in vision os but plane was not roatating.

Can we please get a [mcve]?
